# render :update do |page| tries to render template "update"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render, missing-template

what i'm trying to do is change the list of available for select localities, based on option selected in locality_type select. Both selects are rendered on the facilities/_form.html.erb . I have the following code in LocalitiesController

```
def index
@localities = Locality.all(:conditions => {:locality_type => params[:locality_type]},
                           :order => 'name')
loc_select_id = params[:element_id]
render (:update) do |page|
  localities_options = options_from_collection_for_select(@localities, 'id', 'name')
  page.replace_html loc_select_id, localities_options
end
end
```

This method is called from address.js like that:

```
var locTypeElem = $('select#locality_type');
var locElem = $("select[name$='[locality_id]']");
var locQuery = '/localities?locality_type=' + locTypeElem.val()
   + '&element_id=' + locElem.attr('id')
$.get(locQuery, null, null, 'script');
```

I didi it before, but what goes wrong this time is i get the following Error message in my development log:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template localities/update, application/update    with {:formats=>[:js, "application/ecmascript", "application/x-ecmascript", :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json], :locale=>[:ru, :ru], :handlers=>[:builder, :erb]}. Searched in:
 * "D:/Work/Reserv.by/app/views"
 * "D:/Dev_apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views"
 * "D:/Dev_apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.4.2/app/views"
 ):
 app/controllers/localities_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 3.1.0.rc5 according to gem list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototype and RJS have been removed from Rails 3.1 to a separate gem `prototype-rails`. Make sure you include it in your Gemfile.

Comment: Thank you, it fixed the errror, but the replacement still doesn't happen.  Sending a request like `http://localhost:3100/localities?locality_type=city&element_id=facility_address_attributes_locality_id` gives me a request `Element.update("facility_address_attributes_locality_id", "<option value=\"2\">London</option>\n<option value=\"1\">Paris</option>");` but the page doesn't change

Comment: Did you include prototype inside your application.js? Rails 3.1 includes jquery there by default.

Comment: Yes, I did include `//= require prototype
    //= require prototype_ujs
    //= require effects
    //= require dragdrop
    //= require controls` as in prototype-rails README

Answer (score 0):

Well, since Prototype is deprecated, I tried a different solution: 
LocalitiesController now returns data, not the script:

```
def index
@localities = Locality.all(:conditions => {:locality_type => params[:locality_type]},
                           :order => 'name')
render :inline => "<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@localities, 'id', 'name') %>"
end
```

This data is processed by AJAX then:

```
function selectLocalitiesByLocalityType()
{
var locTypeElem = $('select#locality_type');
var locElem = $("select[name$='[locality_id]']");
var locQuery = '/localities?locality_type=' + locTypeElem.val()
$.ajax({
    url: locQuery,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        locElem.empty();
        locElem.append(data);},
    error: function(data) {alert(data);}
        });
return false;
}
```